# Probability that the entries of a sample covariance matrix of a m.v. Gaussian exceeds a threshold

Tags: probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix of $n$ data points in $\mathbb{R}^p$. So $\Sigma$ is $p\times p$. Suppose that the $n$ points are drawn from the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\vec{0},\Sigma_{\text{true}})$.

What can one say about the number of entries of $\Sigma$ exceeding a certain threshold?

Comment: How do you define a treshold for a **matrix**? For some numeric function like determinant or trace? Or in the positive definite order? ...

Comment: Read link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#/media/File:GaussianScatterPCA.svg

Comment: @Carl: I don't see the point of your link ... I now see the OP asks about a treshold on *each of the matrix*s elements, but I fail too see a statistical context where that gives meaning ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't know, having trouble understanding myself. One possible context might measure the deviations along the axes of an $n$-dimensional data object.

Comment: The question title should be changed to reflect my question, which I think is written sensibly enough. This kind of thing comes up, for example, when looking at sparse choices of $\Sigma_{true}$, where thresholding can improve estimation, ala Bickel and Levina. The choice of threshold for finite samples can be impacted by the answer to such a question. I'm wondering what we can say in general about it.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to add such background, references and some examples of tresholds you are interested in

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, if I ever get time I may do this, but I wrote this a long time back and don't remember too much about the specifics I was curious about. I may have thought this was a productive research direction to go in, but ultimately I went to other places.